# VBA function for array of RGB color combinations and procedure to color large number of cells with unique colors

Tags: vba, excel

Submitting for review by experts.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62367589/9808063) to color value cell having duplicates with a different color. So "Apple" will have one color for all duplicates. Then "Banana" will have a different color for all its duplicates. What if number of such values exceeds 56 (max number of [ColorIndex property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex) ?

With this function I am trying to create array of all possible combinations in a given range and step of RGB colors in VBA.

Starting from 1 and ending 255 there are `256*256*256 = 16,777,216` (1 is added for absence of color, 0) unique combinations of RGB colors. More than enough for all excel rows :) Refer [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487795/9808063). However Excel permits only 64000 format styles. Refer [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel#:%7E:text=Cause,are%20applied%20to%20a%20cell.)

```
Function RGBColorArray(Optional StartCol As Byte = 150, Optional EndCol As Byte = 240, _
Optional Calc_ColStep As Boolean = True, Optional ColStep As Byte = 1, _
Optional Number_of_Cells As Long = 1, Optional Skip_Black As Boolean = False) As Variant
'This function gives array of combinations of colors
'Function will return error if StartCol or EndCol > 255
'StartCol is the color number from where to start. Say 150 default value
'EndCol is the color number where to end. Say 240 as default value
'Default 240 - 150 = 90 gives 90*90*90 = 729000 unique color combinations, enough for excel
'However Excel permits only 64000 format styles.
'Refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel#:~:text=Cause,are%20applied%20to%20a%20cell.
'ColStep is the desired gap/interval between the two consecutive color combinations
'If every color combination is desired then ColStep = 1
'If every 5th color combination is desired then ColStep = 5

Start:
If Calc_ColStep = True Then
ColStep = (EndCol - StartCol) / WorksheetFunction.Max(((WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.Power(Number_of_Cells, 1 / 3), 0)) - 2), 1)
    If ColStep < 1 Then 'This could happen if color range (end-start) is not enough for Number of cells is
    StartCol = 150
    EndCol = 240
    GoTo Start
    End If
End If

Dim RndEndCol As Integer
RndEndCol = StartCol + WorksheetFunction.MRound(EndCol - StartCol, ColStep)
If RndEndCol > 255 Then
EndCol = EndCol - ColStep
'Though this could be EndCol = RndEndCol - ColStep but it returns the same result of final array.
End If

Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte, x As Byte, i As Long, j As Byte, k As Byte, l As Long
Dim arr As Variant, arrVal As Variant
x = 2 + (EndCol - StartCol) / ColStep
ReDim arr(1 To x ^ 3, 1 To 3)
    
StartCol = StartCol - ColStep
'_________________________________________
r = 0: l = 0
For i = 1 To x
    g = 0
    For j = 1 To x
        b = 0
        For k = 1 To x
            l = l + 1
            arr(l, 1) = r
            arr(l, 2) = g
            arr(l, 3) = b
            If b = 0 Then
            b = StartCol + ColStep
            Else
            If b <> 0 And k < x Then b = b + ColStep
            End If
        Next
        If b = 0 Then
        b = StartCol + ColStep
        Else
        If b <> 0 And k < x Then b = b + ColStep
        End If
        If g = 0 Then
        g = StartCol + ColStep
        Else
        If g <> 0 And j < x Then g = g + ColStep
        End If
    Next
    If b = 0 Then
    b = StartCol + ColStep
    Else
    If b <> 0 And k < x Then b = b + ColStep
    End If
    If g = 0 Then
    g = StartCol + ColStep
    Else
    If g <> 0 And j < x Then g = g + ColStep
    End If
    If r = 0 Then
    r = StartCol + ColStep
    Else
    If r <> 0 And i < x Then r = r + ColStep
    End If
Next

If Skip_Black = True Then
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i - 1, 1) = arr(i, 1): arr(i - 1, 2) = arr(i, 2): arr(i - 1, 3) = arr(i, 3)
    Next i
End If

RGBColorArray = arr
    
End Function
```

So, following procedure will color range E1:E125 with different RGB color combinations returned by the above function. Function is `RGBColorArray(150, 240, False, 30, , False)`. 125 cells is result of 5 step colors (0,150,180,210,240). So, `5*5*5 = 125`

```
Sub ColorMyRange()
' This procedure colors each cell in a given range/ selection with unique color
Dim Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte, rng As Range
Dim cell As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long

Set rng = Selection 'WWWWWWW Enter this Range
Number_of_Cells = rng.Cells.Count

RGB_Start = 10 'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default is 150
RGB_End = 240   'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default if 240
'If this color range is not enough for number of cells then formula uses default.

arr = RGBColorArray(RGB_Start, RGB_End, , , Number_of_Cells, True)
'True for skipping first combination row of RGBColorArray of black color RGB(0,0,0)
x = UBound(arr, 1)
Debug.Print UBound(arr, 1) & vbTab & UBound(arr, 2)
i = 1
For Each cell In Selection
    cell = arr(i, 1) & " | " & arr(i, 2) & " | " & arr(i, 3)
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))
    i = i + 1
    Application.StatusBar = i
Next

End Sub
```

Column A, B and C contains array of `RGBColorArray` function

[image]
[image]

With following function we can calculate `ColStep` for the `RGBColorArray` function.

```
Function Calculate_ColStep(Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte)
Calculate_ColStep = (RGB_End - RGB_Start) / ((WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.Power(Number_of_Cells, 1 / 3), 0)) - 2)
End Function
```

Following function returns second half of the `RGBColorArray` upside down.

```
Function TwoDArraySecondHalf(myArray)
Dim myArray2ndHalf() As Variant

Dim a As Long, xa As Long, xb As Long, x2 As Long, b As Long, y As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
a = LBound(myArray, 1): xa = UBound(myArray, 1)
b = LBound(myArray, 2): y = UBound(myArray, 2)
xb = Int(xa / 2)
ReDim myArray2ndHalf(1 To (xa - xb), 1 To 3)
x2 = UBound(myArray2ndHalf, 1)
j = 1
For i = xa To (xb + 1) Step -1
    myArray2ndHalf(j, 1) = myArray(i, 1)
    myArray2ndHalf(j, 2) = myArray(i, 2)
    myArray2ndHalf(j, 3) = myArray(i, 3)
    j = j + 1
Next
TwoDArraySecondHalf = myArray2ndHalf
End Function
```

Using above functions in following procedure, we can color selected cells with alternate (dark/bright) unique colors while skipping black color (first element of `RGBColorArray`, `RBG(0,0,0)`)

```
Sub ColorMyRangeAltCol()
' This procedure colors each cell in a given range/ selection with unique color
Dim Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte, rng As Range
Dim cell As Range, arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
Dim Cell_Address As New Collection

Set rng = Selection 'WWWWWWW Enter this Range
Number_of_Cells = rng.Cells.Count

If Application.Power(Number_of_Cells, (1 / 3)) Mod 1 = 0 Then
Number_of_Cells = Number_of_Cells + 1
End If

RGB_Start = 215 'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default is 150
RGB_End = 216   'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default if 240
'If this color range is not enough for number of cells then formula uses default.

arr = RGBColorArray(RGB_Start, RGB_End, , , Number_of_Cells, True)
'True for skipping first combination row of RGBColorArray of black color RGB(0,0,0)
x = UBound(arr, 1)
arr2 = TwoDArraySecondHalf(arr)

arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To (UBound(arr, 2) - UBound(arr2, 1)))
arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

For Each cell In Selection
Cell_Address.Add cell.Address
Next

i = 1
For j = 1 To Cell_Address.Count Step 2
    Range(Cell_Address(j)) = arr(i, 1) & " | " & arr(i, 2) & " | " & arr(i, 3)
    Range(Cell_Address(j)).Interior.Color = RGB(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))
    If i > Cell_Address.Count / 2 Then Exit For
    Range(Cell_Address(j + 1)) = arr2(i, 1) & " | " & arr2(i, 2) & " | " & arr2(i, 3)
    Range(Cell_Address(j + 1)).Interior.Color = RGB(arr2(i, 1), arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 3))
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Following image shows such example for 250 cells.
[image]
[image]

With following procedure, we can randomly color each cell as shown in the image below.

```
Sub RandomColorMyRange()
' This procedure colors each cell in a given range/ selection with unique random color
Dim Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte, rng As Range
Dim cell As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
Dim ColorsColl As New Collection

Set rng = Selection 'WWWWWWW Enter this Range
Number_of_Cells = rng.Cells.Count

RGB_Start = 100 'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default is 150
RGB_End = 240   'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default if 240
'If this color range is not enough for number of cells then formula uses default.

arr = RGBColorArray(RGB_Start, RGB_End, , , Number_of_Cells, True)
'True for skipping first combination row of RGBColorArray of black color RGB(0,0,0)
x = UBound(arr, 1)

For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
ColorsColl.Add arr(j, 1) & " | " & arr(j, 2) & " | " & arr(j, 3)
Next
ColorsColl.Remove (ColorsColl.Count)
'for removing last duplicate color caused by Skip_Black = True in the RGBColorArray function

For Each cell In Selection
    i = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, ColorsColl.Count)
    cell = ColorsColl.Item(i)
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(Split(ColorsColl.Item(i), "|")(0), _
                                Split(ColorsColl.Item(i), "|")(1), _
                                Split(ColorsColl.Item(i), "|")(2))
    ColorsColl.Remove (i)
    Application.StatusBar = ColorsColl.Count
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you went to 240 instead of 255?

Comment: No , that is just for example to show how we can select the bottom and the top end. Like 120-220, 150-250, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer after many edits to the question and trials of the array function. Best one can be seen in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM4rwlzs5_8). Fixed errors and following function is the result. Please suggest improvements. Thank you

```
Option Explicit
'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
Function Color_Array(Optional RGB_Array As Boolean = False, Optional Number_of_Cells As Long = 1, _
        Optional First_Shade As Byte = 140, Optional Last_Shade As Byte = 240, _
        Optional Shade_Step As Byte = 25, Optional Skip_Black As Boolean = True)
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This function gives array of combinations of RGB colors
'There are two array options
' -- > (1) RGB Array (values for red, green and blue) For this ensure "RGB_Array" boolean is true
' -- > (2) Long Color Values. For this ensure "RGB_Array" boolean is false
'First_Shade is the color number from where to start. Say 140 default value
'Last_Shade is the color number where to end. Say 240 as default value
'Default 240 - 150 = 90 gives 90*90*90 = 729000 unique color combinations, enough for excel
'However, Excel permits only 64000 format styles.
'Refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel#:~:text=Cause,are%20applied%20to%20a%20cell.
'Shade_Step is the desired gap/interval between the two consecutive shades
'If every color combination is desired then Shade_Step = 1
'Say, if every 5th color combination is desired then Shade_Step = 5
'We can skip the first black color RGB(0,0,0), with Skip_Black = True
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Declaration of variables
Dim r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte ', Shade_Step As Byte
Dim i As Byte, j As Byte, k As Byte, l As Long, Number_Of_Shades As Long
Dim arr As Variant
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Caculations of variable values
Number_Of_Shades = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Number_of_Cells + 1) ^ (1 / 3), 0)
Shade_Step = WorksheetFunction.Min(Shade_Step, WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(((Last_Shade - First_Shade + 2) / (Number_Of_Shades - 1)), 0))
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Sizing array depending on whether RGB_Array and Skip_Black booleans are true or false
If RGB_Array = True Then
    If Skip_Black = True Then
        ReDim arr(1 To ((Number_Of_Shades ^ 3) - 1), 1 To 3)
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To Number_Of_Shades ^ 3, 1 To 3)
    End If
Else
    If Skip_Black = True Then
        ReDim arr(1 To ((Number_Of_Shades ^ 3) - 1), 1 To 1)
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To Number_Of_Shades ^ 3, 1 To 1)
    End If
End If
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Loop populating array
r = 0
l = 0
For i = 1 To Number_Of_Shades
    g = 0
    For j = 1 To Number_Of_Shades
        b = 0
        For k = 1 To Number_Of_Shades
            l = l + 1
'--------------------------------------
'Populate array depending on whether RGB_Array and Skip_Black booleans are true or false
            If RGB_Array = True Then
                If Skip_Black = True And l > 1 Then
                    arr(l - 1, 1) = r
                    arr(l - 1, 2) = g
                    arr(l - 1, 3) = b
                Else
                    arr(l, 1) = r
                    arr(l, 2) = g
                    arr(l, 3) = b
                End If
            Else
                If Skip_Black = True And l > 1 Then
                    arr(l - 1, 1) = RGB(r, g, b)
                    Else
                    arr(l, 1) = RGB(r, g, b)
                End If
            End If
'--------------------------------------
            If b = 0 Then b = First_Shade Else b = b + Shade_Step
        Next
        If g = 0 Then g = First_Shade Else g = g + Shade_Step
    Next
    If r = 0 Then r = First_Shade Else r = r + Shade_Step
Next
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Color_Array = arr
End Function
'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Here is VBA code for [the YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM4rwlzs5_8).

```
Sub RandomColorMyRange()
' This procedure colors each cell in a given range/ selection with unique random color
Dim Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte, rng As Range
Dim cell As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
Dim ColorsColl As New Collection, CellAddress As New Collection

Set rng = Selection 'WWWWWWW Enter this Range
Number_of_Cells = rng.Cells.Count

RGB_Start = 100 'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default is 150
RGB_End = 240   'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default if 240
'If this color range is not enough for number of cells then formula uses default.

arr = Color_Array(False, Number_of_Cells, RGB_Start, RGB_End, 50, True)
'First boolena RGB_Array = false
'Second boolean Skip_Blank = True for skipping first row black color RGB(0,0,0)
'enter max shade_step (upto 255) for max rnage of colors
x = UBound(arr, 1)

For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
ColorsColl.Add arr(j, 1)
Next

For Each cell In Selection
CellAddress.Add cell.Address
Next

For Each cell In Selection
    i = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, ColorsColl.Count)
    j = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, CellAddress.Count)
    
    If CellAddress.Count <> 1 Then
    Range(CellAddress.Item(j)) = ColorRGBValue(ColorsColl.Item(i), 2)
    Range(CellAddress.Item(j)).Interior.Color = ColorsColl.Item(i)
    ColorsColl.Remove (i)
    CellAddress.Remove (j)
    
    Else
    Range(CellAddress.Item(1)) = ColorRGBValue(ColorsColl.Item(i), 2)
    Range(CellAddress.Item(1)).Interior.Color = ColorsColl.Item(i)
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = CellAddress.Count
Next

End Sub
```

Following is additional procedure

```
Sub ColorMyRange() 'Not random
' This procedure colors each cell in a given range (or selection) with unique color at given shade_step
Dim Number_of_Cells As Long, RGB_Start As Byte, RGB_End As Byte, rng As Range
Dim cell As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
Dim Cell_Address As New Collection

Set rng = Selection 'WWWWWWW Enter this Range
Number_of_Cells = rng.Cells.Count

RGB_Start = 100 'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default is 150
RGB_End = 240   'WWWWWWW Enter this value or default if 240
'If this color range is not enough for number of cells then formula uses default.

arr = Color_Array(False, Number_of_Cells, RGB_Start, RGB_End, 200, True)
'First boolena RGB_Array = false
'Second boolean Skip_Blank = True for skipping first row black color RGB(0,0,0)
'enter max shade_step (upto 255) for max rnage of colors
x = UBound(arr, 1)
'Debug.Print UBound(arr, 1) & vbTab & UBound(arr, 2)
i = 1
For Each cell In Selection
    cell = ColorRGBValue(arr(i, 1), 2)
    cell.Interior.Color = arr(i, 1) 'RGB(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3))
    i = i + 1
    Application.StatusBar = i
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `ColorRGBValue` function used in both the procedures above is [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216193) named differently.